# linq string.join

Tags: linq

How can I get the ID along with a concatenated list of names using linq?

```
from m in menu
    select new
    {
       id = m.menuHeadingID, 
       items = String.Join(", ", m.menuItemName)
    }
```

The above query does not concatenate all menuItemName values for a single menuHeadingID.

Comment: what is the type of the property `menuItemName`? You should add more detail to your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you *actually* need to group:

```
var menus = menu.GroupBy(m => m.MenuHeadingID)
                .Select(g => new { 
                    Id = g.Key, 
                    Items = string.Join(", ", g.Select(m => m.MenuItemName))
                 });
```

(I've adjusted the property names to follow .NET naming conventions.)